# How can I replace =\ in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, find

I have the following small test script and I want to replace `=\` with `=`
I have no idea why it does not work. Maybe someone can help me

This is my attempt:

```
input = r"asdffdsa\=qwert,  trewert\=qwerqwer"
print input
output = input.replace("=\\", "=")
print output

print input.find("=\\")
```

I get the following output:

```
asdffdsa\=qwert,  trewert\=qwerqwer
asdffdsa\=qwert,  trewert\=qwerqwer
-1
```

Comment: It should be input.replace("\=", "=")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `=\` in your input, you have `\=`. So replacing every `=\`, even if you do it completely right, isn't going to have any effect.

Comment: Pity to see a retaliation downvote on this, and on your highest-voting answer.

Comment: If it was retaliation, I didn't downvote the other (now-deleted) answer. (It wasn't even here last time I saw this page… but even if it were, I don't see anything downvote-worthy.) Maybe whoever downvoted that one also downvoted mine too.

Comment: Perhaps it was retaliation for some other perceived slight. :-) I saw a downvote on this and your highest-voted answer within seconds of one another.